Why are modern philosophers so reluctant to discuss the Creator and the process of Creation?
I would like to understand why people become so defensive as soon as philosophical discussion gets into the areas covering things beyond our known reality.
Why do questions related to God or other 'Creator' concepts become so ideological?


Why do questions related to God or other 'Creator' concepts become so ideological?

I'd love to see some of those discussions centered around evidence, but alas...

Cosmologists are not afraid.
Writers simply love these topics.
Then why philosophers?

Gods and goddesses are divisive figures. They motivate religious wars. They judge. They attract an odd species of judgmental people who deem themselves insiders to the will of gods and goddesses and then impose their will on others. Many philosophers, particularly contemporary scientifically educated simply see no need for divisive supernatural characters or those who believe in them. This question isn't philosophical at all; it's sociological.

@Marxos You can add ur reopen vote (I believe)

It has very little to do with God, creator, even religion.
And everything to do with the history (and geography) of Christianity.
Notice the profile of secularism in politics and you will see a curious spectacle
US
Trump/Republicans are right wing and have warm relations with the (evangelical) Church
UK
Cross the pond and the Labor-Tory divide is very little one way or other to do with the Church
France
Le Pen is "far right". And rigorously secular.
Hmmm... What gives??
The answer happens when you reach Rome
Italy
Secularism is so paramount that Italy carved a piece of its own flesh out of its heart and said: Vatican?! Please be a separate state!! We respect the Pope. But kindly lay off our politics!
All this can be expanded to centuries of history.
The Short version
As you came closer to Rome the domineering increased. (In the past)
And hence the reaction. (Still continues!)
In short, most of secularism is a reaction to (the history of) the Papacy.
That is why US is happy flirting with religious fundamentalists — it had no bad experiences. Unlike Europe.
And Russia which had its own flavor of Christianity for one millenium has a completely different take on secularism
The Answer
So what's the answer to your question?
You think your question is philosophical. [It is]
But your listeners (at least from the western world) hear it as treading on their century old insecurities.
So they dont respond from logic (leave aside philosophy).
They respond from their insecurities
Let me give you an example:
Richard Dawkins
Dawkins is a famous current atheist.
He makes the case that it is absurd that there are some 25 seats in the UK parliament reserved for Anglican bishops.
Fair enough.
But is that a philosophical point? Or a political one?
I'd argue its not even a very political one like Is democracy or socialism better?
Its a very specific local argument in current day UK politics.  Who are you fooling when you make it sound like a grand philosophy-theology issue?
Russell

I remember a relevant anecdote which Tagore related
to me years ago in Calcutta.

Tagore: I was in Cambridge then
and Russell took me out for a morning walk.
We were passing by a Catholic Church where a
choir was singing. I suggested going in to hear the
beautiful hymns.
Russel: No, thank you!
The hymns and incense and coloured glasses make me confess
to feelings my intellect does not approve ; I want to
keep my mental sky clear of the mystic clouds.

Among the Great

Clearly Russell is not saying he is not religious (a cognitive point) but he doesn't want to be emotionally affected.
Also people in those days and so atheists in particular were more honest than today — compare Russell and Dawkins.

Thank you for a great answer, as always. It is even more weird for me. Because I would never reference a religion (even as advanced as Buddhism) when discussing philosophical questions about the Creator.

I dont understand the point you're trying to make with Dawkins?  He made a statement about the intersection of politics and religion in his country.  What is the issue with his non-philosophical stance not really being philosophical, how is that dishonest?  If I quoted Hume giving his opinion on a meal, would you consider it dishonest because it's not philosophy, even though he was talking about food not philosophy, in the first place?

@JMac  I'll need to track down the specific debate which (IIRC) was on (a)theism or some topic of that nature. If you complain anout a meal then quote Hume on a meal and make some (right or wrong) claim on empiricism, someone could well ask you to keep unrelated matters separate. Just to be clear, I'm not saying that Dawkins is dishonest in this particular point, just irrelevant. Dawkins is generally not honest and a bad philosopher is a separate point. Mu point here is just this: Anglican bishops is not a philosophy point

@Rushi I dont see why that statement is even a problem in an (a)theism debate... theistic institutions in the government seems pretty on-topic for a (a)theism debate.  Why does it matter if it's not a philosophy point when the topic was (a)theism?

@JMac Is theism the same as religion? If you say yes then you're a Christian. If you say no there can be a more interesting conversation. And that conversation would be philosophical, not political pretending philosophical like this Q/A. Hint: Consider the downvotes on this answer. Are they philosophical ?

You mentioned some historical context - what's the logical inference that gets you from that to your claim of insecurities? Because it doesn't seem to follow. Your examples also don't seem to support your claim - you can argue semantics about whether Dawkins was making a philosophical point or a political ones, but neither directly imply insecurity. Also, it's irrational to generalise based on one example; but maybe you ended up with that conclusion through some questionable inference based on the historical facts, or maybe you have some other form of justification (which you didn't provide).

@Rushi Theism and religion are heavily related, especially in the country Dawkins is from, and using as an example.  With the little (no) context you give, I'd have to be very ungenerous with my interpretation of it to immediately think Dawkins isnt making a relevant point.  And what are you implying about the downvotes?  IMO this answer is like a big non-sequitur, and it seems like I'm not the only one who doesnt understand.  Your answer is hard to follow, I'm not sure if I'd call it a philosophical reason for the votes, but there are other reasons answers can be bad.

I don't know that there's a broad reluctance or defensiveness. And any of that might exist for a variety of reasons, such as:

Some people might disagree with a theist's reasoning, which may be perceived as defensiveness (whether it is or not).

Some people might see a lack of practical implications of certain god concepts (e.g. deism or pantheism), and thus aren't inclined to discuss that.

Some people might feel strongly about their opposition to the idea given their perception of the harm caused by specific religious beliefs or religion and magical thinking more broadly (which is of course distinct from reasons to believe that any given religion is true or justified).

Of course, on the other side of things, theists might have their entire sense of identity ingrained into their religious belief, and they commonly believe there are eternal consequences to hanging onto that belief. So that can certainly cause a lot of reluctance or defensiveness if someone's challenging that.
And the line between defensive and aggressive is blurry, so defensiveness on one side may feed into defensiveness on the other side.

People may also feel that any given god-related topic is outside of the scope of what they want to talk about or outside the scope of whatever platform is being used.



No answer is an answer (sometimes)

@TheMatrixEquation-balance If only we could accept "no answer" in questions about the Creator.

You have my +1 for the penultimate para (alone ). In practice aggressiveness and defensiveness can be indistinguishable. In any case neither is cognitive, just affective (emotional)

It is also a herd mentality. They want to maintain order and prevent creative thinking.

@TheMatrixEquation-balance I like creative thinking, but if someone can't give a compelling justification to think some hypothesis is true, then just slap a "fiction" label on it and have fun.

In the western world, discussing gods has moved to theology since naturalism and science left too few gaps to require a single god of the gaps. There are no miracles observed often enough (or at all) to be subject to scrutiny or further philosophic thinking.
Morality is based on secular values and reasoning while religions are based on scriptures of predominantly sexist, racist, superstitious nature. As in God wants you to mutilate your body, not shave, not eat during special times, avoid eating pork, wear a funny little hat, hide your face, obey your fascist parents, marry a person you don't love, deny your sexuality, pray only to that one god, not wear condoms and so on...
The plurality of religions in a globalized world each with their own scriptures prevents any useful philosophical discussion on scripture.
Therefore discussing gods now mostly looks like marketing for this cult or that trying to recruit members.
Another reason might be that through science, humanity has accumulated so much knowledge to study that a single lifetime is not nearly enough to be an expert in many things, and that leaves philosophers little time to study the traditions, scriptures and superstitions of this cult or that, as they would do in the past.
The churches are also not powerful enough anymore to gatekeep funds or rights to publish, so philosophers in the west don't have to produce writings to appease churches anymore.
But if one misses those days, in several Islamic countries I would assume secular education and ideology to be so low that philosophers might still be writing about gods, and how to best kill unfaithful spouses or commit acts of terror in the name of God to faithfully follow scripture.

"tkruse" - This is wrong: "Morality is based on secular values and reasoning while religions are based on scriptures of predominantly sexist, racist, superstitious nature" - Religion - is a cultural inheritance. This is how people lived and survived for thousands of years. If you don't care about culture or do not inherit much of it, then it is not a problem of religion or the culture represented by it.

Right, if there is one Creator, why so many views about that? We don't have 47 different takes on gravity or arithmetic in each city you visit.

@TheMatrixEquation-balance humans love and survived in caves for thousands of years. Do you live in a cave? Well I don't, and my morality is not based on a grandfatherly type peeping on me in the shower deciding if I am good enough for playing in his garden. But suit yourself.

@ScottRowe - If you think about it, there is no other way. The Creator - is an eternal mystery that drives our civilization forward. Once we reach the end point and understand our Creator - the process will end.

@tkruse - Wisdom comes with age (sometimes). If you were wise and understood the game of life at an earlier age, you would not achieve anything significant in your life.
